# Nullable types in .net

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

Why does

```
properties[5].PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == 
   Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1")
```

equals to true while

```
properties[5].PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
   Type.GetType("System.Nullable")
```

equals to false?

`Properties[5]` being a `public Nullable<DateTime>` field.

What does the ``1`after the`System.Nullable` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `1 means that the type is a generic type. Since it's possible to have a type called "Foo" as well as a type called "Foo" then there needs to be some internal way for the two types to be differentiated.

Since there's a non-generic `System.Nullable` type but you're using a generic type, your comparison to GetType("System.Nullable") will always return false.

Answer (score 3):

Nullable`1 is the real name of the class you know of as Nullable<T> in C# (Or Nullable(Of T) in VB.Net).

Nullable is a static class with a number of helper methods for using Nullable<T>.